# Vue.js - Why does the function repeats every time?

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am trying to execute this code with vuejs just every time that I go into the

**component:**

```
created() {
     this.getPosts();
     setInterval(function () {
        this.getPosts();
     }.bind(this), 2000);
},
```

I want to execute the serInterval just one time, just when I go into the component how I said before but it keeps reloading every single moment, I do not want that, how can I do that this `serInterval` execute only one?

Comment: As Iokomov mentioned, you should use a `setTimeout` instead. However, what's the purpose of running the same function you ran just 2 seconds before? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use setTimeout instead :

```
 setTimeout(function () {
        this.getPosts();
     }.bind(this), 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what `setInterval` is supposed to do, if you are willing to stop it manually think about adding `clearInterval()` to your code, if not, `setTimeout` might do your job.

Check [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_scheduling_timers)